# How to place the TextArea text in its center?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textarea

I have a Dialog and a `TextArea`. The `TextArea` component has an alignment set to `Component.CENTER`. I created a method named `affiche()` which displays the Dialog :

```
public class Alert extends Dialog {
    private TextArea chp;
    private Command[] comms;
    public Alert(String text, Command[] comms)
    {
        super();
        this.comms = comms;
        setAutoDispose(true);
        for (int c=0; c<comms.length; c++)
            addCommand(comms[c]);
        chp = new TextArea(text);
        chp.setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        chp.setEditable(false);
        chp.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(null);
        chp.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(null);
        chp.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(this.getStyle().getBgColor());
        chp.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(this.getStyle().getBgColor());
        chp.setRowsGap(3);
    }
    public Command affiche()
    {
        return show(null, chp, comms);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the text is displayed at the top of the `TextArea` when calling the `affiche()` method from another Form.

So how to display the text in the center of the `TextArea` ? I mean by "center" the center in the width and the center in the hight. I already set the horizontal alignement to center by the code `chp.setAlignment(Component.CENTER);` , so I want to know how to set the vertical alignement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution without using the DefaultLookAndFeel class. Here it is :

```
public class Alert extends Dialog {
    private TextArea chp;
    private Command[] comms;
    public Alert(String text, Command[] comms)
    {
        super();
        this.comms = comms;
        setAutoDispose(true);
        for (int c=0; c<comms.length; c++)
            addCommand(comms[c]);

        chp = new TextArea();
        chp.setAlignment(Component.CENTER);
        chp.setEditable(false);
        chp.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(null);
        chp.getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(null);
        chp.getSelectedStyle().setBgColor(this.getStyle().getBgColor());
        chp.getUnselectedStyle().setBgColor(this.getStyle().getBgColor());
        while (text.substring(0, (text.length()/2)+1).length() < chp.getMaxSize()/2)
        {
           text = " ".concat(text);
        }
        chp.setText(text);
    }
    public Command affiche()
    {
        return show(null, chp, comms);
    }
}
```

So I just added the `while` code. And it works !

Answer (score 2):

My previous answer was wrong, I forgot what we did by now...

TextArea supports center alignment even though its undocumented just set the style to center align and it will work out of the box.

Comment: Please give us and example of how to implement this

Comment: I tried below code. It is working in project.
textArea.getStyle().setAlignment(CENTER);
// Here textArea is instance of TextArea